# AngularJS - $emit not passing actual values

Tags: angularjs

Here is my html method call from the html page:

```
data-ng-click="handleNav('{{subItem.module}}','{{subItem.url}}')">{{subItem.name}}</a>
```

From the user's perspective, source code sees this:

```
data-ng-click="handleNav('Mod1','inserts/Pages/Default')" class="ng-binding">Sub 1</a>
```

However in my child conntroller emit call:

```
        $scope.handleNav = function (args1, args2) {
        console.log(args1);
        console.log(args2);
        $scope.$emit('changeView', (args1, args2));
    };
```

..... these are the console log's values:

```
   {{subItem.module}}
   {{subItem.url}}
```

..... when they should be:

```
    Mod1
    inserts/Pages/Default
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution:**

```
 data-ng-click="handleNav(subItem.module,subItem.url)">{{subItem.name}}</a>
```

Most strange, because had I not used $emit and had the actual function handling the navigation in the child controller all would have been well, and the function in the parent controller that handles this navigation is essentially the same as what is in the child controller.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to interpolate (`{{x}}`) variables for ng-click, but it doesn't need it. Think of ng-click like javascript code. It has access to your scope variables, etc.

To fix, drop the `'` and `{{` and `}}`

```
<a data-ng-click="handleNav(subItem.module, subItem.url)">{{subItem.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting values in single quote which is an indicator to not evaluate expressions. Hence variables are passed as strings and not their values

Comment: What is the solution then? I cannot remove the single quotes from the page.

Comment: Also angular Will itself pass values. You don't have to put double curly braces while passing parameters to functions

Comment: I'd you wants single quote around values use string concatenation